# CastError: Cast to ObjectID failed for value {{Campground.name}} (type string) at path "_id" for model "Campground"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Campground, User, Review } = require("./modules/mainModule")

const ejs = require("ejs");
const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');

const Joi = require("joi");
const flash = require("connect-flash");

const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const methodOverride = require("method-override");
const customError = require("./public/javascript/customError");
const catchAsync = require("./public/javascript/catchAsync");
const { validateCampground } = require("./schemas");

const campgroundRoute = require("./routes/campgrounds");

const app = express();
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(\__dirname, "/views"));

app.engine("ejs", ejsMate);

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/public', express.static(\__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(methodOverride('\_method'));

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/campdb')
.then(() =\> {
console.log("Mongoose connected");
})
.catch((err) =\> {
console.log("ERROR!");
console.log(err);
})

const sessionConfig = {
secret: "super",
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: true,
cookie: {
httpOnly: true,
expires: Date.now() + 1000 \* 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 7,
maxAge: 1000 \* 60 \* 60 \* 24 \* 7
}
}

app.use(session(sessionConfig));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(flash());

app.get("/", catchAsync(async (req, res, next) =\> {
let i = 0;
const features = \[\];
while (i != 5) {
const feature = await Campground.findOne({ rating: 5 });
features.push(feature);
i++;
}

    res.render("index.ejs", { features });

}))

app.use((req, res, next) =\> {
res.locals.success = req.flash("success");
res.locals.error = req.flash("error");
next();
})

app.use("/campgrounds", campgroundRoute);

app.get("/about", (req, res) =\> {
res.render("about");
})

app.get("/contacts", (req, res) =\> {
res.render("contacts");
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) =\> {
const { message = "wazaaa", statusCode = 500 } = err;

    res.status(statusCode).send(message);

})

app.listen("8080", () =\> {

    console.log("Listening on port 8080");

})
```

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
const flash = require("connect-flash");

const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const { Campground, User, Review } = require("../modules/mainModule")
const customError = require("../public/javascript/customError");
const catchAsync = require("../public/javascript/catchAsync");
const { validateCampground } = require("../schemas");
const app = express();




router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    const foundCampgrounds = await Campground.find({});
    res.render("campgrounds", { foundCampgrounds });
})

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews");
    res.render("campground", { campground });
})

router.post("/", async (req, res) => {

    const campground = await new Campground({ ...req.body.campground });
    await campground.save();
    req.flash("success", "You have created a campground");
    res.redirect(`campgrounds/${campground._id}`);
})


router.get("/new", async (req, res) => {
    res.render("new");
})


router.post("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    const review = await new Review({ comment: `${req.body.campground.comment}`, rating: req.body.campground.rating });

    campground.reviews.push(review);
    await review.save();
    await campground.save();


    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${campground._id}`);
})

router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { ...req.body.campground });
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${id}`);
})

router.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate();
    for (let review of campground.reviews) {
        await Review.findByIdAndDelete(review._id);
    }

    campground.delete();
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
})

router.delete("/:id/:id2", async (req, res) => {
    const { id, id2 } = req.params;
    await Campground.findByIdAndUpdate(id, { $pull: { reviews: id2 } });
    await Review.findByIdAndDelete(id2);
    res.redirect(`/campgrounds/${id}`);
})

router.get("/:id/edit", async (req, res) => {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id);
    res.render("edit", { campground });
})

module.exports = router;
```

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true

    },

    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0
    },

    description: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },

    image: {
        type: String
    },

    location: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },

    owner: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },

    contacts: {
        type: String,
        // required: true
    },

    ratings: {
        type: Number
    },

    reviews: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "review"
        }
    ]


})

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        default: ""
    },

    comment: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    rating: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        required: true
    }
})


const Campground = mongoose.model("Campground", campgroundSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const Review = mongoose.model("review", reviewSchema);

module.exports = { Campground, User, Review };`
```

in my "/" get route I list my campgrounds. I have seeded a bunch of them in. Here I can click on a name of the campground and it takes me to "/:id" get route. I can refresh the page and everything works fine and the id is in the link.

In my "/" get route I have a link to "/new" where I can create a new campground. It creates and normally redirects me to that campground get route "/:id". Now If I reload the page I get this error and a "something went wrong" page. I also get this error if I try to access the campground from the get "/" route where it produces the error gets me to the campground page but once again gives me a "something went wrong" page upon reloading.

As I look into the error I'm really confused on why is getting the campground.name value and is trying to cast it to ObjectId. Why does it even load the page in the first place and then doesn't.

I checked the database and the campground is there and all it's values are in place as they should be.

really confused here

EDIT:

campgrounds list ejs:

```
<%- include("../views/parts/head.ejs"); %>

    <body>

        <%- include ('./parts/navbar.ejs'); %>

            <p>
                <%= success %>
            </p>

            <form action="/campgrounds/new" method="get">
                <button>Create Campground</button>
            </form>

            <main>
                <% for(let el of foundCampgrounds) { %>
                    <div>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="campgrounds/<%= el._id %>">
                                <%= el.name %>
                            </a>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            <%= el.description %>
                        </p>
                        <table>

                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%= el.location %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <%= el.price %>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <%= el.ratings %>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </div>

                    <% } %>
            </main>
            <%- include("../views/parts/footer.ejs"); %>
    </body>

    </html
```

Specific campground EJS:

```
<%- include("../views/parts/head.ejs"); %>

    <body class="bg-white txt-black">

        <%- include("./parts/navbar_yellow.ejs"); %>

            <%= success %>

                <div>
                    <h3>
                        <%= campground.name %>
                    </h3>
                    <p>
                        <%= campground.description %>
                    </p>

                    <p>
                        <img src="<%= campground.image %>" alt="">
                    </p>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= campground.owner %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= campground.location %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= campground.contacts %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <%= campground.price %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= campground.ratings %>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <a href="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id %>/edit">Edit Campground</a>
                    <a href="/campgrounds">All Campgrounds</a>
                    <form action="/campgrounds/<%= campground._id%>?_method=DELETE" method="post">
                        <button>Delete Campground</button>
                    </form>

                    <% if(campground.reviews) { %>
                        <% for(let review of campground.reviews) { %>
                            <div>
                                <h3>
                                    <% if(review.username) { %>

                                        <%= review.username %>

                                            <% } else {%>
                                                Bazooka
                                                <% } %>
                                </h3>
                                <p>
                                    <%= review.comment %>
                                </p>
                                <div>
                                    <span>5/<%= review.rating%></span>
                                </div>
                                <form action="<%= campground._id %>/<%= review._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="post">
                                    <button>Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <% } %>
                                <% } %>



                                    <div>
                                        <h1>
                                            <%= campground.name %>
                                        </h1>

                                        <form action="<%= campground._id %>" method="post">

                                            <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="campground[comment]"
                                                placeholder="This place is the best!" required>

                                            <label for="rating">Rating:</label>
                                            <input type="number" name="campground[rating]" min="0" max="5" required>

                                            <button>Submit</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                </div>
                <%- include("../views/parts/footer.ejs"); %>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Can you show the front-end code related to the error?

Comment: @lpizzinidev yeah, added it to post

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the exact `GET` requests sent by the browser.
For me the cause of this error was some `dummy_image` data in the DB for the image. Using that in img tag as `src="dummy_image"` caused the browser to send a `GET` request to `/dummy_image` which was caught by the `.get("/:id")` route using `"dummy_image"` as the value of `id`.

Another problem in your code is that the `.get("/:id")` route should be below other get routes. Otherwise it will also catch requests like `"/new"` and use `new` as an `id`, causing the same `CastError` when you query the DB.

**General take-away:** it's a good practice to always check the `id` before querying the DB:

```
if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
    const campground = await Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("reviews");
    res.render("campground", { campground });
}
else {
    res.status(404).send(`Got invalid ID: ${id}`);
}
```